# How to get Iconfiguration and IHostingenvironment in .net 4.7?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I keep finding how to do this for .net core, but I am working on a library for netstandard and if i want to use this library in .net 4.7 as well how can I access the iconfiguration and the ihosting environment when I am in .net 4.7. I keep finding info that you need to do dependency injection to get it to work, but no one shows code examples of how it is done.

I keep finding these lines of code on all the info that I been reading, saying something about injecting them there:

```
    public class Startup
   {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
    }
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {   
    }
}
```

how do I get the .net core iconfiguration/ihostingenvironment equivalent in .net 4.7+?

Comment: those are as.net core concepts, not asp.net framework concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startup code here is usually the .NET Core...for 4.7 with MVC, you usually call the `DependencyResolver.SetResolver` from the Global.asax (`Application_Start()` method) using whatever DI framework you want (Unity, SimpleInjector, Autofac, etc).

Here is the suggested snippet from SimpleInjector:

```
// You'll need to include the following namespaces
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc;

public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    // This is the Application_Start event from the Global.asax file.
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Create the container as usual.
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();


    // Register your types, for instance:
    container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    // This is an extension method from the integration package.
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    container.Verify();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

From: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html?highlight=mvc

**UPDATE**

The IHostingConfiguration and IConfiguration are interfaces only implemented with .NET Core and are unavailable in .NET 4.7.

Comment: Do I really need to use a DI framework? there is no other way around that?

Comment: It looks like i missed your main question on IConfiguration and IHostingEnvironment....I thought you were wanting to use DI in .NET 4.7. Those are interfaces implemented only in .NET Core, which is why you haven't found code for using them in 4.7.  What are you planning to do with them?

Comment: In my netstandard library, I need to get the hosting environment, but im unsure how to do a global solution that will work for both core an .net 4.7+

Comment: What about the hosting environment are you looking up?

Comment: HostingEnvironment.IsHosted and mappath specifically

Comment: Not familiar with IsHosted, but you may need consuming app to provide web.config or app.config having an app setting to implement IsProduction or likewise methods yourself.  For MapPath, you can use the method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.mappath?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I meant mappath in core hahaha